# Is there a pre-established method for cracking RSA SecureID codes?

Tags: rsa, server, usb

I am using the most modern version of RSA SecureID's tokens with a RSA server (used with a lot of governments and larger organizations ). I was just wondering if there was a pre-established method for cracking these codes having access only to a RSA code(i.e. reverse engineering).

General information about RSA codes:

RSA SecureID Server (seed code). Code changes every 60 seconds.

RSA SecureID USB (identical see code). Code changes every 60 seconds.

The RSA SecureID code allows you to log into an online system by comparing the SecureID you have entered by reading your portable USB device screen to the code in the server.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle

Comment: I just had a brief look at this article, it looks like it describes the ideology behind security systems, which basically suggests that they should be designed to be unbreakable. While this helps affirm my view that RSA SecurIDs cannot be broken, it does not really identify any actual established methods for breaking this system. 

I know it has been done on other RSA systems, google RSA SecureID 800 and you will see what I mean, but for the modern RSA SecureIDs there does not really seem to be a publicly available method for cracking these codes.

Comment: Please do not take the information in this particular Question as evidence that an RSA SecureID hack does not exist. While some research has been undertaken to determine whether it does or not, there may actually be a hack available. This question will be updated if a hack is found. Watch this space.